# Recieved a nmea sentence with an invalid checksum

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I have attached a GPS Neo 6M module to raspberry pi 3. I installed nmea_navsat_driver package and run the following command:

rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_serial_driver _port:=/dev/ttyS0

it prints out some messages but with an **invalid checksum warning.**

I can see a rostopic named /fix but when I echo it, the following message prints out and then nothing appears:

**Warning: no messages recieved and simulated time is active. Is /clock being published?**

What are the reasons and solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275914/recieved-a-nmea-sentence-with-an-invalid-checksum/) by [ZanaZak](https://answers.ros.org/users/30251/zanazak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're GPS module is producing fix data in the wrong format i.e. not nmea format. I recommend using [putty](http://www.putty.org/) or a similar serial terminal to see the raw data being produced by your GPS module, and if you the specification for it you should be able to adjust the GPS module to produce output in the right format.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0